# Small electric shock from toaster when plug is ungrounded

Tags: ground, safety

I have a toaster which is supposed to be grounded. Some sockets in my home are not grounded and some are grounded. When the toaster is connected to an ungrounded socket, the metal casing could cause a very small electric shock (I was almost unable to feel it when touching it directly, but a contact voltage tester lights up dimly).

When connecting the toaster to a grounded socket, the electric shock on the metal case disappear and a contact voltage tester wouldn't light up.

I know that the metal casing is grounded for safety so that if there is a fault and a line wire touches the metal casing, my circuit breaker will trip automatically. But the circuit breaker didn't trip, the electric shock was only mild and the problem disappear when using grounded socket.

Is the toaster somehow faulty? I know using grounded socket is important when the appliance requires one. I read somewhere that this might be intentional and that there is a capacitor connecting the line wire with the metal case. Another article suggested eddy current.

Edit: The toaster is Kambrook KTA 270.

Comment: We can't know without knowing more about the toaster. If it's a fancy toaster with electronics inside and a switchmode power supply, it might have line to ground Y capacitors that can cause this...

Comment: Can you give us the make and model. Also it would help if we knew part of the world this is as electrical systems are different.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the effect by simply flipping the plug?   Have you checked to make sure the socket is wired correctly?  (Surprisingly common).   Sometimes an outlet box is grounded but has a 2 pin socket....many grounding adaptors have a small tab for connecting to the screw that holds the outlet cover in place, which would ground the plug.   Lastly,  a GFCI will prevent you from getting electrocuted and they work WITHOUT a ground wire present...consider installing one.   If the toaster can make a GFCI trip, throw away the toaster.

Comment: The toaster is a Kambrook KTA 270. The case won't electrocute when it is connected to a grounded socket and only electrocute on an ungrounded socket. Even that is only small tingle.

Answer (score 2):

The toaster is fine.  When you connect the toaster to a grounded socket you force the metal case to the same potential as everything else in your house. When it's not connected the case is floating and there can be differences in voltage potential. If you plug your toaster into the ungrounded socket you will be able to use a voltmeter to measure the voltage to something grounded, like your sink.

In any case I wouldn't worry about the toaster, but you should get those ungrounded sockets fixed as soon as you can. They are supposed to be grounded for a reason.